# iOS Swift 2.3: correct syntax for application restorationHandler?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to setup **Firebase Dynamic Links** in my iOS project using Swift 2.3.

When I add this function in the AppDelegate (as reported at the bottom of this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios)), I get the error:

> Unknown attribute 'escaping'

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let dynamicLinks = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {
       return false
    }
    let handled = dynamicLinks.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) {
       (dynamiclink, error) in
       // ...
    }
    return handled
}
```

any idea which is the correct syntax for Swift 2.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method which you are using is for `swift3`, here is the method for `swift2.3`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add restriction on deep link then implement bellow method like this 
this delegate method call first.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool {


    return userActivityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb ? true : false

}
```

if you want to link which user have click or if you have multiple deep link in single app then want to identify then you can get like this.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool{
    // pass the url to the handle deep link call
    print(userActivity.webpageURL)
    //NSURLComponents
    return true
}
```